# What is the best way to add flashing to this part of my roof?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, flashing, fascia

About 25% of the edges of my house have exposed fascia boards like in these pictures. I’ve never done any roof work but this seems like an obvious mistake committed when the builder constructed the home about 10 years ago. For some of the 1st story boards, I’ve cut them and repainted them, but now I’m ready to add a metal drip edge like the other edges of the house. What’s the best way to do this? Tips and tricks appreciated!

[image: exposed fascia board, 1st story]

[image: exposed fascia board, 2nd story]

Comment: It is quite common for the gable fascia to stick out.  My last three houses had it so!!!!